# OR-tools VRP solver returning one job per vehicle

Tags: or-tools, vehicle-routing

I am using Google OR-Tools in python to solve a capacitated VRP with pickup/delivery. In many cases the solver works well and returns reasonable solutions, but we have found that for some data sets the solver will always return one job per truck regardless of the time involved for the route.

I have the model set up as follows:

My initial vehicle count is equal to the number of jobs in the data-set, and we allow OR-Tools to automatically minimize the truck count.

Each job's pickup location has a demand of 1 and each job's dropoff location has a demand of -1, to enforce delivery immediately after pickup.

We set the maximum drive time per vehicle to 8 hours.

Then, each job has an associated quantity attached for pickup, and we separate this job into multiple deliveries based on a truck's capacity. For instance, if a job requires 60 tons delivered, we represent that as three jobs at 20 tons each (the maximum a vehicle is allowed to carry on an interstate in the U.S)

Now, we have a simple data set with a pickup location at: 698 Longtown Rd, Columbia, SC and a dropoff location at: 121 Chappell Creek Rd Hopkins, SC. This is a drive time of 32 minutes, or a total trip time of 64 minutes. This job has an associated quantity of 60 tons, which will require 3 truck loads.

The results we receive from or-tools shows one load per truck, and this result **does not change** regardless of how long we allow the solver to run. The optimal solution would allow one truck to complete all loads, as this is still drastically under the 8 hour drive time limit.

Here is my code:

```py
import json
import math
import traceback
import urllib
import redis
import requests

import boto3
from signal import signal, SIGINT, SIGTERM

from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp, routing_enums_pb2

url = 'https://test-api.truckit.com/api/2/signin'
api_data = {"password": "", "username": ""}
response = requests.post(url, json=api_data)
api_data = response.json()


def build_auth_header(token):
    header = {'Authorization': f'Token {token}'}
    return header


class SignalHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.received_signal = False
        signal(SIGINT, self._signal_handler)
        signal(SIGTERM, self._signal_handler)

    def _signal_handler(self, signal, frame):
        print(f"handling signal {signal}, exiting gracefully")
        self.received_signal = True


sqs = boto3.resource("sqs")
queue = sqs.get_queue_by_name(QueueName="")
redisClient = redis.Redis(host='', port=6379,
                          password='')


def create_distance_matrix(data):
    addresses = data["addresses"]

    API_key = data["API_key"]
    origin_addresses = []
    dest_addresses = addresses
    distance_matrix = []
    responses = {}
    responses['destination_addresses'] = []
    responses['origin_addresses'] = []
    responses['rows'] = []

    # Send q requests, returning max_rows rows per request.
    for i in range(0, len(addresses)):
        origin_addresses.clear()
        origin_addresses.append(addresses[i])

        for j in range(0, len(addresses), 25):

            dest_addresses_request = addresses[j:j + 25]

            response = send_request(origin_addresses, dest_addresses_request, API_key)
            responses['origin_addresses'] = response['origin_addresses']
            for destination_address in response['destination_addresses']:
                responses['destination_addresses'].append(destination_address)
            for row in response['rows']:
                if len(responses['rows']) == 0:
                    responses['rows'].append(row)
                else:
                    for element in row['elements']:
                        responses['rows'][0]['elements'].append(element)

        distance_matrix += build_distance_matrix(responses)
        responses['origin_addresses'].clear()
        responses['destination_addresses'].clear()
        responses['rows'].clear()

    return distance_matrix


def send_request(origin_addresses, dest_addresses, API_key):
    """ Build and send request for the given origin and destination addresses."""

    def build_address_str(addresses):
        # Build a pipe-separated string of addresses
        address_str = ''
        for i in range(len(addresses) - 1):
            address_str += addresses[i] + '|'
        address_str += addresses[-1]
        return address_str

    request = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial'
    origin_address_str = build_address_str(origin_addresses)

    dest_address_str = build_address_str(dest_addresses)
    request = request + '&origins=' + origin_address_str + '&destinations=' + \
              dest_address_str + '&key=' + API_key

    jsonResult = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()
    response = json.loads(jsonResult)

    return response


def build_distance_matrix(response):
    distance_matrix = []
    for row in response['rows']:
        row_list = [row['elements'][j]['duration']['value'] for j in range(len(row['elements']))]
        distance_matrix.append(row_list)

    return distance_matrix


def process_message(message_body):
    print(f"processing message: {message_body}")
    data = json.loads(message_body)
    data_matrix = {}
    data_matrix['problem_id'] = data['problemId']
   
    data_matrix["addresses"] = []
    data_matrix["pickups_deliveries"] = []
    data_matrix["demands"] = []
    data_matrix["jobOrderIDs"] = []
    depot_address = str(data["depot"]["latitude"]) + "," + str(data["depot"]["longitude"])
    data_matrix["jobOrderIDs"].append(0)
    data_matrix["addresses"].append(depot_address)
    hash_key = data["hashKey"]

    for location in data["locationList"]:

        pick_lat = location["PickupLatitude"]
        pick_long = location["PickupLongitude"]

        drop_lat = location["DropoffLatitude"]
        drop_long = location["DropoffLongitude"]

        jobOrderId = location["jobOrderID"]

        demand = math.ceil(float(int(location["totalQuantity"]) / 20))


        for i in range(0, demand):
            data_matrix["addresses"].append(str(pick_lat) + ',' + str(pick_long))
            data_matrix["addresses"].append(str(drop_lat) + ',' + str(drop_long))
            data_matrix["jobOrderIDs"].append(str(jobOrderId))
            data_matrix["jobOrderIDs"].append(str(jobOrderId))

    data_matrix["demands"].append(0)
    for i in range(1, len(data_matrix["addresses"]) - 1, 2):
        data_matrix["pickups_deliveries"].append([i, i + 1])
        data_matrix["demands"].append(1)
        data_matrix["demands"].append(-1)

    data_matrix["num_vehicles"] = int(len(data_matrix["addresses"]) / 2)
    data_matrix["vehicle_capacities"] = []

    for i in range(0, data_matrix["num_vehicles"]):
        data_matrix["vehicle_capacities"].append(1)

    data_matrix["depot"] = 0
    data_matrix["API_key"] = ''

    data_matrix["distance_matrix"] = create_distance_matrix(data_matrix)

    # Create the routing index manager.
    manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(len(data_matrix['distance_matrix']),
                                           data_matrix['num_vehicles'], data_matrix['depot'])

    # Create Routing Model.
    routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)

    # Define cost of each arc.
    def distance_callback(from_index, to_index):
        """Returns the manhattan distance between the two nodes."""
        # Convert from routing variable Index to distance matrix NodeIndex.
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
        return data_matrix['distance_matrix'][from_node][to_node]*1000

    transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(distance_callback)
    routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)

    # Add Distance constraint.
    dimension_name = 'Duration'
    routing.AddDimension(
        transit_callback_index,
        0,  # no slack
        28800*1000,  # vehicle maximum travel hours
        True,  # start cumul to zero
        dimension_name)
    distance_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(dimension_name)
    distance_dimension.SetGlobalSpanCostCoefficient(100)

    def demand_callback(from_index):
        """Returns the demand of the node."""
        # Convert from routing variable Index to demands NodeIndex.
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        return data_matrix['demands'][from_node]

    demand_callback_index = routing.RegisterUnaryTransitCallback(
        demand_callback)
    routing.AddDimensionWithVehicleCapacity(
        demand_callback_index,
        0,  # null capacity slack
        data_matrix['vehicle_capacities'],  # vehicle maximum capacities
        True,  # start cumul to zero
        'Capacity')


    # Define Transportation Requests.
    for request in data_matrix['pickups_deliveries']:
        pickup_index = manager.NodeToIndex(request[0])
        delivery_index = manager.NodeToIndex(request[1])
        routing.AddPickupAndDelivery(pickup_index, delivery_index)
        routing.solver().Add(
            routing.VehicleVar(pickup_index) == routing.VehicleVar(
                delivery_index))
        routing.solver().Add(
            distance_dimension.CumulVar(pickup_index) <=
            distance_dimension.CumulVar(delivery_index))
    
    # Setting first solution heuristic.
    search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
    search_parameters.local_search_metaheuristic = (
        routing_enums_pb2.LocalSearchMetaheuristic.GUIDED_LOCAL_SEARCH)
    search_parameters.time_limit.seconds = 1200
    search_parameters.log_search = True
    search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
        routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.AUTOMATIC)
    search_parameters.use_full_propagation = True
    # Solve the problem.

    solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)

    if solution:
        solution_dict = {}

        for vehicle_id in range(data_matrix['num_vehicles']):

            index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
            plan_output = ''
            route_distance = 0
            route_load = 0
            while not routing.IsEnd(index):
                node_index = manager.IndexToNode(index)

                plan_output += '{0},'.format(data_matrix['jobOrderIDs'][node_index])
                previous_index = index
                index = solution.Value(routing.NextVar(index))

            plan_output += '{0},'.format(data_matrix['jobOrderIDs'][manager.IndexToNode(index)])

            plan_output = plan_output[:-1]
            plan_words = plan_output.split(",")
            plan_output = ''
            for i in range(len(plan_words)):
                if (i % 2 == 0):
                    plan_output += plan_words[i] + ","
            plan_output = plan_output[:-1]
            plan_output += ",0"
            if plan_output != 0 and plan_output != str(0) and plan_output != str('0,0'):
                print(plan_output)
                solution_dict[vehicle_id] = plan_output

        # trucks_url = 'https://test-api.truckit.com/api/2/trucks'
        trucks_url = 'https://test-api.truckit.com/api/2/job-orders/smart-dispatch/' + str(data_matrix['problem_id'])
        head = build_auth_header(api_data["authToken"])
        status = {}
        ride_list = []
        dummy_location_dict = {}
        dummy_id_dict = {}
        dummy_id_dict["id"] = 0
        dummy_id_dict["name"] = ""
        dummy_location_dict["location"] = dummy_id_dict
        dummy_location_dict["timestamp"] = 0

        ride_list.append(dummy_location_dict)

        redisClient.hset(hash_key, "solution", json.dumps(solution_dict))
        redisClient.hset(hash_key, "ride_list", json.dumps(ride_list))
        json_data = {"status": "completed"}

        api_response = requests.post(trucks_url, headers=head, json=json_data)

        print_solution(data_matrix, manager, routing, solution)


def print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution):
    """Prints solution on console."""
    print(f'Objective: {solution.ObjectiveValue()}')
    total_distance = 0
    total_load = 0
    for vehicle_id in range(data['num_vehicles']):
        index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
        plan_output = 'Route for vehicle {}:\n'.format(vehicle_id)
        route_distance = 0
        route_load = 0
        while not routing.IsEnd(index):

            node_index = manager.IndexToNode(index)

            plan_output += ' {0} -> '.format(node_index)
            previous_index = index
            index = solution.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
            try:
                distance = data['distance_matrix'][previous_index][index]
                route_distance += distance
            except:
                distance = distance

        plan_output += ' {0}\n'.format(manager.IndexToNode(index))
        plan_output += 'Time of the route: {} hours\n'.format(str(float(route_distance / (60 * 60))))
        print(plan_output)
        total_distance += route_distance

    print('Total distance of all routes: {}m'.format(total_distance))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    signal_handler = SignalHandler()
    while not signal_handler.received_signal:
        messages = queue.receive_messages(
            MaxNumberOfMessages=1,
            WaitTimeSeconds=1
        )
        for message in messages:
            try:
                process_message(message.body)

                message.delete()

            except Exception as e:
                print(f"exception while processing message: {repr(e)}")
                traceback.print_exc()
                continue

            message.delete()
```

IF anyone has any suggestions as to what the problem may be, your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also posted to OR-Tools forum and potential answers discussed there https://groups.google.com/g/or-tools-discuss/c/t6nAKnmSChA